# How to config two oracle datasource in spring boot?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, datasource

I faced problem when trying to config two oracle datasource (PCP & PP) in spring boot jpa app.

Can someone guide me what is the wrong with my config?

```
PCPDatabaseConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' that could not be found.
```

Structure and config of application is as follows:

**application.yml config :**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myapp
    group: pp
    product: YYY
    area: delivery
    host: ${HOST:localhost}
  profiles:
    active: ${ENV}
  jmx.enabled: false
  datasource:
    pp:
      platform: oracle
      connection-init-sql: call DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE ('${spring.application.name}', null)
      jmx.enabled: false
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    pcp:
      platform: oracle
      connection-init-sql: call DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE ('${spring.application.name}', null)
      jmx.enabled: false
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

**Structure :**

[image]

**PCPDatabaseConfig :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.xxx.repository.pcp")
public class PCPDatabaseConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.pcp")
    public DataSource pcpDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .build();
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate pcpJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("pcpDataSource") DataSource pcpDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(pcpDataSource);
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.jpa")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapterOraclePCP() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryPCP")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryPCP(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = builder
                .dataSource(pcpDataSource())
                .packages("com.xxx.repository.pcp")
                .persistenceUnit("oracle")
                .build();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapterOraclePCP());
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oraclesqlTransactionManagerPCP")
    public PlatformTransactionManager oraclesqlTransactionManagerPCP(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryPCP") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

**PPDatabaseConfig :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.xxx.repository.pp")
public class PPDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.pp")
    public DataSource ppDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate ppJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("ppDataSource") DataSource ppDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ppDataSource);
    }


    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryPP")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryPP(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder
    ) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = builder
                .dataSource(ppDataSource())
                .packages("com.xxx.repository.pp")
                .persistenceUnit("oracle")
                .build();
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
    @Bean(name = "oraclesqlTransactionManagerPP")
    public PlatformTransactionManager oraclesqlTransactionManagerPP(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryPP") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't add code as images as those are totally unreadadble. Post as text with code tags for proper formatting and readability. You also didn't explain what problems you did encounter.

Comment: Please use code tags for the yaml as well, your structure overview isn't complete either. I would also suggest to ditch the `JpaVendorAdapter` as Spring Boot will add the correct one automatically. Your datasource configuration is also a bit off, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources. You would only need 1 single `@EnableTransactionManagment` (actually you wouldn't need it at all) and you need to specify the `entityManager` and tx manager for `@EnableJpaRepositories` as well.

Comment: Finally make sure you aren't excluding the JPA Autoconfiguration somehow as that is the part that builds the `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem as follows (also updated the question after finding the problem):

1.Using `@EnableJpaRepositories` like:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories( entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryPCP",
        basePackages = "com.xxx.repository.pcp")
public class PCPDatabaseConfig {
```

And

```
    @EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryPP",
            basePackages = "com.xxx.repository.pp")
public class PPDatabaseConfig {
```

And

Using exact   `@Bean(name="transactionManager")` like :

```
  @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager oraclesqlTransactionManagerPCP(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryPCP") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
```